# Null validation in Hive , looking for best approach

Tags: hive

I have condition in datastage which verifies 30 columns as not null and assigning value as '0' if anyone of the field is null like below,

`isnull(columnA) or isNull(coloumnB) or isnull(columnC) or isNull(coloumnD) then 0 else 1.`

we have option to use case statement in hive to set values, however we have to give use CASE statement per column like below,

```
select 
 case when (columnA is NULL) then 0 
 case when (columnB is NULL) then 0 
 case when (columnC is NULL) then 0 
 .
 .
 .
 else 1 
end as iValidColumn
From tablea
```

What i am looking?

Trying to look for option where we can validate all the 30 columns in condition for null validation.

Comment: Hive has an isnull function, but you'll still need to wrap all the tests in a case statement: `case when isnull(col1) or isnull(col2)...then 0 end`.

Comment: Does the table contain more than 30 columns? What is the final output you are looking for?

Comment: How about coalesce function ?

Comment: @Andrew this helps minimize the number of case statement.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz it contains more than 30 columns and i am trying to get these fields validated and extract only not null values and rest will be to error table.

Comment: @cricket_007 i feel Coalese works for all feilds with AND condition, however this one is OR condition. have tried Caolesce as well.

Comment: coalesce(x,y, 1) == If X is null, use Y if not null. If X and Y are null, then 1... Is that AND? `1 if (isnull(x) and isnull(y)` ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Coalesce will return y if x is null and y is not null value. what i am looking for is even if one of the value is null in this case x.. i would need 0 instead of 1.

Comment: You could define a UDF to do this. I'm not aware of a hive function that does what you need